# Button responding after loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application using jquery that iterates through a series of checkboxes.

while it iterates through, I have a dialog showing the status of the printing session. I also have a cancel button to cancel the session.

```
<input type="button" id="cancelButton" onclick="cancel()">

    function cancel() {
        stop = true;
    }
```

Through each iteration I check if `stop` is true and if it is, I break out of the loop. The problem however is that if I press the cancel button during the session, the cancel function will only run after the `.each` loop (kind of defeating the purpose). Is there a way to make the button more responsive or a better way to approach this?

Comment: you may have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066714/javascript-exit-from-javascript-loop-when-button-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Run the functions in separate threads?

```
setTimeout(function() { $('[name=check]:checked').each(function() {
    printingFunction();
}); }, 1);
```

Comment: Unless you chain the set timeouts together I fear this will queue them all up at once and your button press still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain `setTimeout`s in order to make it possible to check for a Stop. You'd still have to wait for the current operation to complete, but it would let you break out of the loop.

```
function next()
{
    printingFunction();
    if (!stop && someOtherCheck)
        setTimeout(function() { next(); }, 1);
}

next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can interrupt the `.each` loop as **JavaScript execution is single threaded.**

However I think **timers are executed asynchronously**, you might try something like below to cancel and clear.

Something like the logic below may get you there.

```
var timeouts = [];

$.each(someArray, function(index, value){
    timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(){
          console.log(index);
     },5000*index));
});


$('#cancel-button').click(function(){
    $.each(timeouts, function (_, id) {
       clearTimeout(id);
    });

    timeouts = [];
}):
```

**Also**, you may consider playing with [**.index()**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) if the above doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it again - I made a change to the shift statement that will clear the error in IE 11:

```
var ele = Array.prototype.shift.call($checked);
```

You need to use setTimeout on the each loop call (can be set to 0) so the cancel function gets a chance to execute - something like this:

```
function cancel() {
    stop = true;
}
function printingFunction() {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < 10000){
        x+=1;
    }
}

function printLoop($checked) {
    if (stop) {
        console.log('Stopped - button pushed')
    } else {
        if ($checked.length > 0) {
            var ele = Array.prototype.shift.call($checked);
            printingFunction()
        }
        if ($checked.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(function(){printLoop($checked)}, 0);
        } else {
            console.log('Stopped - array depleted')
        }

    }

}

var stop = false,
        $checked = $('[name=check]:checked');

printLoop($checked)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the solution but for `Array.shift($checked)` I kept getting an error telling me that shift() wasn't recognized (I'm using IE11 to run my app), is there an alternative? And just as a curiosity, is there anyway to mimic your logic if I had a `printRow()` inside a for loop in the `printingFunction()`? Wouldn't I then just make recursive calls in the `printingFunction()`?

Comment: Note the code edit above.  You could do something similar for rows - depends on what the print function is actually doing...